# How to make the width of a flow automatically with Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

The width of a flow or stack must be a number, but if I don't know how wide the flow will be, the flow will become as wide as it can. How to make it as wide as it's **child elements**  automatically with Shoes(the Ruby GUI Toolkit)?

Comment: Hm for all that I know that is exactly what a Shoes Flow does, it gets as wide as it has to be to accommodate all its child elements if you don't define a width.

If that's not the case for you please illustrate your problem, e.g. some code and a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

this is dynamic memory allocation.

without more information on what language what you are trying to achieve it is hard to help you further.

@edit

this was a good read...
http://merbist.com/2010/07/29/object-allocation-why-you-should-care/
this article was a crash course for memory managemnt in ruby.

Comment: Sorry, I'v added the description. It doesn't relate to memory. Thank you as well.